# How can I expose SPDK-managed NVMe device as regular block device under Linux?

Tags: linux, storage, solid-state-drive

I am building a project that requires rewriting a new I/O stack that issues I/O requests to NVMe SSDs, and I am currently writing a prototype using **SPDK** to test the preliminary performance. I need to use many benchmarks, e.g., MySQL workloads and YCSB, to test the performance. However, as SPDK implements a distinct I/O stack that is not handled by the operating systems, I can not access the NVMe SSDs as regular block devices under Linux. And SPDK only supports testing with RocksDB and FIO, thus I can not perform the tests using the benchmarks as usual.

Therefore, my question is, how can I **expose the SPDK-managed NVMe SSD as the regular block device under Linux**, while still handling the I/O requests to the SSD using my I/O stack? I heard that this feature is enabled by the SPDK developers, but I can not find how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure this is what you're askng for, but have you looked at [BDev][1]?


  [1]: https://spdk.io/doc/bdev.html

Comment: Thank you for the docs. I have gone through SPDK bdev user guide and it doesn't really fit my needs. I want to write my own block device using SPDK and access it as regular block devices under /dev/ without performance issues. But it seems that SPDK bdev guide didn't tell me how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

ublk Target (https://spdk.io/doc/ublk.html) will help here if you want to access nvme drives using spdk driver.

Other way is to create a remote target over nvmeof. Linux kernel nvme will be able to connect to the remote target via nvmeof (https://spdk.io/doc/nvmf.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great, thank you! I noticed that both methods can bring some overheads to the nvme drive's performance, and which one should I use if I want to maintain the performance?